# If Multiple Versions of a Bundle Are Installed How Can I Find out Which One Is Used?

Tags: osgi, aem

Two different version of a same bundle deployed in AEM and both bundles are in active state. My question How can I figure out which version of bundle is being used currently?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow shah. Can you please be a more specific. The more relevant information you provide the more likely it is that you will get a useful answer. For example: Do you want to find this out programmatically or through some kind of administrative UI? Which OSGi framework are you using.

Comment: It's possible they are both being used... but it all depends what you mean by "used". If the bundles publish a service, their service instances could be used independently by different consumers. If they are exporting packages, other bundles could be importing from either or both.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is most probably to access the [AEM WebConsole, go to "Bundles"](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/sites/deploying/using/configuring-web-console.html#Bundles) tab and then expand the interesting Bundles and then you'll see all other Bundles listed which actually import the packages exported by this bundle for entry "Importing Bundles".

If you have access to the OSGi shell (IDK if AEM allows that), you can also use the `bundle:capabilities <bundle-id>` command, which shows the "wiring" in case an exported package is used, e.g. (from a Karaf installation but would looks very similar):

```
karaf@root()> bundle:capabilities 307                                                                                                                                      21:12:12
org.apache.felix.scr [307] provides:
------------------------------------
osgi.wiring.bundle; org.apache.felix.scr 2.0.8 [UNUSED]
osgi.wiring.host; org.apache.felix.scr 2.0.8 [UNUSED]
osgi.identity; org.apache.felix.scr 2.0.8 [UNUSED]
osgi.wiring.package; org.apache.felix.scr.component 1.1.0 [UNUSED]
osgi.wiring.package; org.apache.felix.scr.info 1.0.0 required by:
   org.apache.felix.scr.compat [133]
osgi.wiring.package; org.osgi.service.component 1.3.0 required by:
   org.apache.felix.scr.compat [133]
osgi.wiring.package; org.osgi.service.component.runtime 1.3.0 required by:
   org.apache.felix.scr.compat [133]
   org.apache.karaf.scr.state [135]
   org.apache.karaf.scr.command [311]
   org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds [351]
osgi.wiring.package; org.osgi.service.component.runtime.dto 1.3.0 required by:
   org.apache.karaf.scr.command [311]
   org.apache.karaf.scr.state [135]
   org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds [351]
   org.apache.felix.scr.compat [133]
osgi.wiring.package; org.osgi.util.function 1.0.0 [UNUSED]
osgi.wiring.package; org.osgi.util.promise 1.0.0 required by:
   org.apache.karaf.scr.command [311]
   org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds [351]
osgi.extender; osgi.component 1.3.0 [UNUSED]
[org.apache.felix.scr [307](R 307.0)] osgi.service; {objectClass=[org.osgi.service.component.runtime.ServiceComponentRuntime]} [UNUSED]
service; [org.osgi.service.component.runtime.ServiceComponentRuntime] with properties:
   service.bundleid = 307
   service.id = 110
   service.scope = singleton
   Used by:
      org.apache.felix.webconsole.plugins.ds [351]
      org.apache.karaf.scr.command [311]
service; [org.apache.felix.scr.impl.ScrGogoCommand] with properties:
   osgi.command.function = [config, disable, enable, info, list]
   osgi.command.scope = scr
   service.bundleid = 307
   service.description = SCR Gogo Shell Support
   service.id = 111
   service.scope = singleton
   service.vendor = The Apache Software Foundation
service; [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService] with properties:
   service.bundleid = 307
   service.description = SCR Configurator
   service.id = 112
   service.pid = org.apache.felix.scr.ScrService
   service.scope = bundle
   service.vendor = The Apache Software Foundation
   Used by:
      org.apache.felix.metatype [2]
```